# How do I run a Minecraft datapack function when a player has a specific item in their inventory?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-data-packs

I'm making a datapack and in it I need to check (in a mcfunction file) if any player (`@a`) has a specific item in their inventory (`minecraft:gold_ingot{coin:1}`) if so, I need to run a function (gc:coin_amount). In-game I have used conditional command blocks to achieve this (`execute as @a run clear @s minecraft:gold_ingot{coin:1}` and then `function gc:coin_amount`), however I have no idea how to pull it off inside a mcfunction file in a datapack.

Any help would be appreciated. I'm on Minecraft 1.15.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the result of a command with `/execute store`. In this case:

```
/execute as @a store result score @s gold run clear @s gold_ingot{coin:1}
```

Then you can use that score for whatever you want. In this case you're just interested in whether it's 1 or more:

```
/execute as @a if score @s gold matches 1.. run <command>
```

As a nice side effect, this also runs the function as every player who matches that condition. If you don't want that, use `/execute if entity @a[scores={gold=1..}] run <command>` instead.

Also, if you just want to check whether someone has an item (or how much of it), without actually taking it away, use the `/clear` command with a count of 0.

Comment: sadly this doesn't seem to work D:

Comment: @SingleSouls Which part of it? What happens instead?

Answer (score 0):

I'm late but if you use a datapack you could simply add an advancment that is hidden in folder datapacks/custom/advancments/item_check/gold_ingot.json

The gold_ingot.json file would be:

```
{
    "criteria": {
        "check":{
            "trigger": "inventory_changed",
            "conditions": {
                "items": [
                    {"items": ["gold_ingot"]}
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "requirements": [
        ["check"]
    ],
    "rewards": {
        "function": "custom:func"
    }
}
```

And the datapacks/custom/functions/tags/func.mcfunction would be:

```
advancement revoke @s only custom:item_check/gold_ingot

#Execute here extra code that the player should do when the item is in their inventory
```